# How to remove element from array A that are also in array B in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Suppose I have array A and array B which contains object. How do I "clean" elements from array A that are also exist in B. That is, I need to remove all element in A that are also in B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding, you're trying to remove all similar items from array A that are present in B?

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    arrayA.splice(arrayA.indexOf(arrayB[i]), 1);
}
```

Do note this only removes ONE of each item in arrayA. If you have multiple of the same instances in arrayA that are present in arrayB, only one will be removed. For multiples of the same instances, use this instead:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
    while(arrayA.indexOf(arrayB[i]) >= 0) {
        arrayA.splice(arrayA.indexOf(arrayB[i]), 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This effectively removes every element of **Array** B that happen to occur in **Array** A;

```
for each (var anItem:Object in B)
{
    var anIndex:int;

    do
    {
        anIndex = A.indexOf(anItem);
        A.splice(anIndex, 1);
    }
    while (anIndex > -1);
}
```